# Hide site link using $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-state

I have two users one is 'admin' and 'user'. I need to when I login as a 'user' hide the some url.

my add_sales.php file include some code

```
<div class="side-menu fl">

    <h3>Sales Management</h3>

    <ul>
        <?php if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'admin' ) {  ?>
            <li><a href="add_sales.php">Add Sales</a></li>
            <li><a  href="view_sales.php">View Sales</a></li> 
        <?php } ?>

        <?php else if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'user' ) {  ?>
            <li><a href="add_sales.php">Add Sales</a></li>
         <?php } ?>
    </ul>

</div> <!-- end side-menu -->
```

when I access as a 'user' I use this code for use user to  if($_SESSION[usertype']=='user') I don't know this is right o wrong please can some one help 
me..
my cheacklog.php is

```
if($count==1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $_SESSION['id']=$row[0];
    $_SESSION['username']=$row[1];
    $_SESSION['usertype']=$row[3];

    if($row[3]=="admin"){
        header("location:dashboard.php");
    }
    else if($row[3]=="user")
    {
        header("location:dashboard.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: if it works then it is right. so does it work?

Comment: Please stop using unrelated tags, your question has nothing to do with CakePHP, just like it has nothing to do with JavaScript or MySQL - thanks!

Comment: @ndm ahhh hahaha, reading that made my morning. Cheers `:-)` (some people are indeed confusing)

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in line.  This link will be inserted into the page only if the user has admin status:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="general.php">All users will see this link</a></li>
<?php

if ($row[3]=="admin") {
    echo "<li><a href='adminStuff.php'>hidden link</a></a>";
}

?>

</ul>
```

I am pretty sure that is what you meant, or if you want to do conditional redirects, I think you already have that done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['userType'] == 'admin'): ?>
      <a>Only admin can see this. </a>
<?php else if($_SESSION['userType'] == 'user' ): ?>
      <a>Only user can see this</a>
<?php endif ?>
```